# How to display all images uploaded with facebook post

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-php-sdk

I'm using facebook SDK for PHP to get post on user timeline. I use api "/me/feed" to get the timeline. The problem is that I can display text only. I want to display all image which uploaded or shared by each post. 
How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

"**me?fields=posts{type}**" - Gives you all posts of authorized user. From that result, you'll get type attribute mentions Link, Photo, and Video. So you can filter photo only to show all user photos.

"**me?fields=photos**" - Gives you all photos of user's tagged(Uploaded by user friends).

"**me?fields=posts{picture}**" Gives you only posts with Photos.(Which you need). The return JSON format is followed.

```
{
  "posts": {
    "data": [
      {
        "picture": "https://fbcdn-photos-d-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-xtp1/v/t1.0-0/s130x130/14718778_1841680516118589_7768474098175322373_n.jpg?oh=6e53b43361b48c3568a72dd5b651d312&oe=588D34A5&__gda__=1486132096_8b0bef43cf74166a9b88391a7bcb9195",
        "id": "319551818195811_717085918443189"
      },
      {
        "picture": "https://fbcdn-photos-c-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-xal1/v/t1.0-0/s130x130/14724654_1745688559098754_6408885771776123938_n.png?oh=9fbab8e118743gbaf2854e60945e5dec&oe=58ABE2A0&__gda__=1486058914_4df4fb64e7b307205bbc3db4fccfc3fa",
        "id": "319551818195811_717085918443189"
      },
      {
        "picture": "https://fbcdn-photos-c-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-xal1/v/t1.0-0/s130o130/14724654_1745633559098754_6435045951276123938_n.png?oh=9fbab8e118746bbaf2854e60945e5dec&oe=58ABE2A0&__gda__=1486058914_4df4fb64e7b307205bbc3db4fccfc3fa",
        "id": "319551818195811_717085918443189"
      }
      }
    ]
}
```

From that JSON, "Picture" is Photo URL which you posted to FB. You can embed to an image tag to show it on your website.

Note : JSON is Modified

Hope This helps :)

Comment: I want to show all post in user's timeline, and all images of each post. Like what seen in facebook wall. Can we do like that?

Comment: Yes you can do that. "me?fields=posts{type}" will give all posts. Just give a try.

Comment: Thanks so much! I try now

Comment: Actually it's not what I'm looking for. What I need is how to get images of each post then display in website. If I upload 2 images with my post, how can I get them and display? Can you show me some code?? Thanks!

Comment: Don't you get image URLs in return JSON?

Comment: Try this "me?fields=posts{picture}", The Return Json is updated to Post above.